# Placing text on top of a image

Tags: html, css

I've been looking on several threads on stackoverflow, but cant seem to make it work. What i've found out is that i need to apply relative position on the parent div and then absolute on the child text, but this is not working? what am i doing wrong`

```css
.the-image { 
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid;
    width: auto;

}

.the-h3 { 
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:150px;
    top:350px;
}

.the-h3 span { 
   color: #ffffff; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="the-image">
    <img style="height: 200px" src="http://i.imgur.com/w15Db.jpg"></img>
    <h3 class="the-h3"><span>TEST</span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the absolute positioning for the `h3` tag?

Comment: That `img` needs alt text. Use null alt text (i.e. `alt=""`) if the image is a background image with no semantic meaning (which appears to be the case here) or use meaningful alt text if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the `h3` a `top` property which is more than the image is high.

Simply lower that value to something more fitting:

```css
.the-image { 
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid;
    width: auto;

}

.the-h3 { 
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:150px;
    top:10px;
}

.the-h3 span { 
   color: #ffffff; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="the-image">
    <img style="height: 200px" src="http://i.imgur.com/w15Db.jpg"></img>
    <h3 class="the-h3"><span>TEST</span></h3>
</div>
```